# The type of the first permission that failed was: - error

Tags: c#, sandbox

I'm trying to make a sandbox to run untrusted code. I have been following the example given in this Microsoft Docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/misc/how-to-run-partially-trusted-code-in-a-sandbox)
However I can't get the program to run properly as I keep getting failed permissions/failed assembly or AppDomain etc..

This is the sandbox code (taken from the example given)

```
class Sandboxer : MarshalByRefObject
{
    const string pathToUntrusted = @"..\..\..\UntrustedCode\bin\Debug";
    const string untrustedAssembly = "UntrustedCode";
    const string untrustedClass = "UntrustedCode.UntrustedClass";
    const string entryPoint = "IsFibonacci";
    private static Object[] parameters = { 45 };
    static void Main()
    {
        AppDomainSetup adSetup = new AppDomainSetup();
        adSetup.ApplicationBase = Path.GetFullPath(pathToUntrusted);

        PermissionSet permSet = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
        permSet.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution));

        StrongName fullTrustAssembly = typeof (Sandboxer).Assembly.Evidence.GetHostEvidence<StrongName>();

        AppDomain newDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Sandbox", null, adSetup, permSet, fullTrustAssembly);
        //new AppDomain.
        ObjectHandle handle = Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(
            newDomain, typeof (Sandboxer).Assembly.ManifestModule.FullyQualifiedName,
            typeof (Sandboxer).FullName
        );
        //untrusted code.
        Sandboxer newDomainInstance = (Sandboxer)handle.Unwrap();
        newDomainInstance.ExecuteUntrustedCode(untrustedAssembly, untrustedClass, entryPoint, parameters);
    }
    public void ExecuteUntrustedCode(string assemblyName, string typeName, string entryPoint, Object[] parameters)
    {
        MethodInfo target = Assembly.Load(assemblyName).GetType(typeName).GetMethod(entryPoint);
        try {
            //Now invoke the method.
            bool retVal = (bool)target.Invoke(null, parameters);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted).Assert();
            Console.WriteLine("SecurityException caught:\n{0}", ex.ToString());
            CodeAccessPermission.RevertAssert();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the untrustedCode(also taken from the example)

```
namespace UntrustedCode {
    public class UntrustedClass {
        public static bool IsFibonacci(int number) {
            File.ReadAllText("C:\\Temp\\file.txt");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

When the program runs the following exception is caught when the target is invoked...

> (System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed. On line 58)
>
> The type of the first permission that failed was:
>   System.Security.PermissionSet The demand was for:
>
> The granted set of the failing assembly was:
>
> The assembly or AppDomain that failed was: UntrustedCode,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=36df3253255c2d3
>
> The Zone of the assembly that failed was: MyComputer The Url of the
>   assembly that failed was:
>   file:///C:Users/Sam/Desktop/SandboxExample/UntrustedCode/UntrustedCode/bin/debug/UntrustedCode.EXE